# Mongoose: Get the data from 2 collections, like get products that have same category type like fruits

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am very new to `mongoDB` and `mongoose` and I also know questions like this has been already asked but still I didn't get any luck.

So what I am trying to do is I have 2 collections one is products and second is categories and I am trying to get the products that are of category type: fruits

**product.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

module.exports = Product
```

**category.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    }
})

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema)

module.exports = Category
```

**products collecction**

```
[ { _id: 5ffc9795355f3707ec326f51,
    name: 'apple',
    price: 80,
    image: 'apple1.jpg',
    description:
     'Do you really need description for this ??',
    category: 5ffc94e8a7542a37101a119c,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5ffd54409793c33b183376b8,
    name: 'Beef',
    price: 180,
    image: 'beef1.jpg',
    description: 'Don\'t you dare to ask about beef in india',
    category: 5ffc94dda7542a37101a119b,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5ffd54969793c33b183376b9,
    name: 'Mango',
    price: 100,
    image: 'mango1.jpg',
    description:
     'Have some manog because you cannot eat the bottle of slice like katrina kaif do, its crazy',
    category: 5ffc94e8a7542a37101a119c,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

**categories collection**

```
[ { _id: 5ffc947ea7542a37101a119a, name: 'vegitables', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5ffc94dda7542a37101a119b, name: 'non-veg', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5ffc94e8a7542a37101a119c, name: 'fruits', __v: 0 } ]
```

**Now I want to the get the products whose category are fruits**

I know I have to use aggregation and lookup for this I also tried but didn't get any luck, this is my code

```
const Product = require('./models/product')
const Category = require('./models/category')

const test = async () => {
    try {
        var query = [
            {
            $lookup: {
                from: "product",
                localField: "category",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "product"
            }
        }]
        const productCate = await Product.aggregate(query)
        console.log(productCate)
        // const productCat = await Product.find().populate({
        //     path: 'category',
        //     match: {name: 'fruits'}
        // }).exec()
        // console.log(productCat)
    }catch(e) {

    }
}

test()
```

**UPDATE-1**

I also tried ppuplate but still didn't get the response as expected, this is my code:

```
const test = async () => {
    try {
        const productCat = await Product.find().populate({
            path: 'category',
            match: {name: 'fruits'}
        }).exec()
        console.log(productCat)
    }catch(e) {

    }
}

test()
```

**this is my output**

```
[ { _id: 5ffc9795355f3707ec326f51,
    name: 'apple',
    price: 80,
    image: 'apple1.jpg',
    description:
     'Do you really need description for this, how dumb are you ??',
    category: { _id: 5ffc94e8a7542a37101a119c, name: 'fruits', __v: 0 },
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5ffd54409793c33b183376b8,
    name: 'Beef',
    price: 180,
    image: 'beef1.jpg',
    description: 'Don\'t you dare to ask about beef in india',
    category: null,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5ffd54969793c33b183376b9,
    name: 'Mango',
    price: 100,
    image: 'mango1.jpg',
    description:
     'Have some manog because you cannot eat the bottle of slice like katrina kaif do, its crazy',
    category: { _id: 5ffc94e8a7542a37101a119c, name: 'fruits', __v: 0 },
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Here I also get the beef that is fall under non-veg category but with the category null. Actually I only want the fruits category products.

Comment: hi try this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: if you scope your code removing un-necessary stuff, and state more clearly what you tried / didn't work, then this will be solved

Comment: I tried to solve this using both populate and aggregation also updated the question, but still no luck, I am sure I am not using them right but that's what I want to know how can I get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can following this code

```
const test = async () => {
  try {
    let categoryId = await Category.findOne({name:"fruits"}).select("_id")
      const productCat = await Product.find({category:categoryId}).populate(
        "category"
      ).lean()
      console.log(productCat)
  }catch(e) {

  }
}

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do with with populate match without using aggregation:

```
Product.find().populate({
path: 'category',
match: { 'name': 'fruits' }
  })
 .exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I already tried this but this still return the whole products including 'beef' but with category property null. Let me add this into the question for better understanding.